# Precise video cut using FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

How can I make exact cut from a video using FFmpeg?
Both of these commands add few seconds in front of desired part:

```
ffmpeg -ss [HH:]MM:SS[.m...] -i input -to [HH:]MM:SS[.m...] -c copy -copyts output
ffmpeg -ss [HH:]MM:SS[.m...] -i input -t [HH:]MM:SS[.m...] -c copy -avoid_negative_ts 1 output
```

Comment: Only transcoding can be assured to deliver closest to a precise cut.

Comment: @Mulvya, what's a transcoding? Changing encoding?

Comment: Yes - recompressing the video.